# A calendar starts on a Monday and returns a 1 to an int weekDay and my code should should do that

Tags: java, calendar, applet

A Calendar starts on a Monday and returns a 1 to an int weekDay and my code should do that. I can't figure out what to do next next since all I tried, i got errors

```
import java.applet.Applet;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.awt.*;

public class Dates2Applet extends Applet  
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {  
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
    int wDay = c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if(Calendar.MONDAY == c.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    {
        System.out.println("Monday is the first day of the week");
    }

    if(Calendar.MONDAY == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    {
        System.out.println("Monday close books");
    }

    if(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    {
        System.out.println("Normal week day");
    }

    if(Calendar.SATURDAY ==0 || Calendar.SUNDAY ==0);
    {
        System.out.println("Match Day");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put a semicolon at the end of your `if` statements it creates a one line body, and then your braces are not tied to the `if` (and that's also why, presumably. `else` didn't work for you) - I think you wanted something like,

```
if(Calendar.MONDAY == c.getFirstDayOfWeek()) {
    System.out.println("Monday is the first day of the week");
}
if(Calendar.MONDAY == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
    System.out.println("Monday close books");
} else if(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
    System.out.println("Normal week day");
} else if(Calendar.SATURDAY ==0 || Calendar.SUNDAY ==0) {
    System.out.println("Match Day");
}
```

Comment: I am just curios to know how form the question you get what the OP wants? the English the op used is not clear. and why given the code out when this is clearly homework?!!!!!

Comment: @KickButtowski I read the code OP posted. OP included this code with the minor differences of not using `else` and having the semicolon on the `if` blocks. Normally, `;` is not semantically significant (but obviously it can create an empty block).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i just wanted the day monday to return to a 1 and hopefully a sunday to be a 7

Comment: @Bhabs Sadly they're constants in [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), so you can't change them and [`Calendar.MONDAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY) is 2. Finally, `SATURDAY` is 7 and `SUNDAY` is 1.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch its ok, all i want is someone to code that and put it to the applet.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i removed the semicolons at the end of the if statements but now it does not print anything to the screen